# Can this triangle be solved?

Tags: triangles

[image: Image of the triangle form the question]
I am struggling with this question. I am unsure if it can be solved or if there is a mistake in it. Specifically, $\angle ADC$ looks to be $90^\circ$ but is not marked as such. So, given that $\angle ADC$ is unknown, can this be solved using the sine or cosine rule? This is meant to be a GCSE level question and I am really struggling to see a simple solution. Thank you.

Comment: There is probably a mistake. Without the $90^\circ$ it is impossible to solve, since the ratio $DC:CB$ can then be changed at will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only features of the diagram that are fixed is the triangle $\triangle ABC$.  You can solve for all angle measures and all side lengths for this triangle.  However, point $D$ relative to this triangle can be positioned at any location along the ray $BC$ such that $BC < BD$.  Therefore, the length of $CD$ is not uniquely determined.  An additional assumption is required but not stated.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose AD is not joined as given and it is required to solve only the acute angled triangle part ABC:

$$\angle CBA = 47^{\circ};\;\angle CAB = 59-47=12^{\circ};AB=49\;; $$

This way it can be solved.